# How to install compatible expo go app for react native expo sdk version?

Tags: react-native, expo

Maybe this is a sily question but I can't find a proper solution in internet. My react native project expo sdk is 45.0.0 but installed expo go app doesn't support expo sdk (only 46+)

I can't upgrade project expo sdk version. How do I find compatible expo go app version and how do I install that in emulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade your Expo SDK version with the command:

```
expo upgrade 46
```

**Note:** You should look for the Deprecations, renamings, and removals from the [expo SDK 46 documentation](https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-46-c2a1655f63f7) before upgrading.

Also, if you wanna downgrade the expo app in your emulator, just uninstall the expo go app, run your server, and click `a` if android and `i` if IOS for downloading the compatible Expo Go which is compatible with your SDK version.

Comment: thanks. expo latest upgrade has issues with building that's why I couldn't upgrade. But I will try the other thing you mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, that's with SDK 48. You can upgrade to SDK 47 it doesn't have any issues.